Live wire 3 | Change image on click | livewire update route goes 404
commrace application using laravel-livewire, in product detail page i want to change images on click thumbnails and also want to fetch image on color select.
i have make multiple publi properties for getting image path from livewire component.
the problem is when i click on wire:click method it's goes me to 404.
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Product;

use App\Services\ProductService;
use Livewire\Attributes\Layout;
use Livewire\Component;

class Detail extends Component
{
    public $slug;
    protected $product;
    public $mainImage;
    public $images;

    public function mount(ProductService $product_service) {
       $this->product = $product_service->getProductDetail($this->slug);
       $this->mainImage = env('APP_URL').'/storage/'.$this->product->image;
       $this->images = $this->product->getMedia('images');
    }

    public function changeMainImage($media){
        $this->mainImage = env('APP_URL').'/storage/'.$media;
    }

    #[Layout('components.layouts.app-without-banner')]
    public function render()
    {   
        if($this->product){
            return view('livewire.product.detail',['product' => $this->product]);
        }else{
            return abort('404');
        }
    }
}

front end
<div class="px-2">
            <div class="border border-solid">
                <img src="{{ $mainImage }}" alt="{{ $product->title }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-center mt-2">
                @foreach ($images as $media)
                    <img class="border border-solid h-16 w-16 mx-auto cursor-pointer" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$media->id.'/'.$media->file_name) }}" wire:click="changeMainImage(`{{ $media->id.'/'.$media->file_name }}`)"/>    
                @endforeach
            </div>
       </div>

unable to update image on-click
update rout exists in route list
php artisan route:list

